# Adding a Regex Constraint on a Rails Route

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a a number of routes that can be like :

```
possible routes:
- mac-book-retina-17-pid234-234
- hp-laptop-pid234-234
- vaoe-x12-pid234-234
```

and I want to match all to one action using the constraints in Ruby route file. Something like

```
get 'products/:product_info', to: 'products#type', constraints: { product_info: /[a-z]+-a-z]+-a-z]+-pid\d+-\d+/ }
```

The problem is that the `/[a-z]+-/` can get repeated 1 time, 2 times and 3 times, and it makes it hard to get a consistent shared Regex for all the cases.
The only part that is constant in all routes is the last part: `pid234-234` which refers to the product id and another sub_id.

I am thinking of something like: find all strings untill you each this part(`pid`), but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/aQ2kO4/1)?

Comment: You can specify the number of repetitions of a group as a range using curly braces, e.g. `([a-z0-9]-){1,4}`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a good place to start is [dynamic-segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments)

```
get 'products/:product_info', to: 'products#type', constraints: { product_info: /[A-Z]\d{5}/ }
```

I hope that this helps

Happy Hacking

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to find a possible solution for this:

```
(.*)pid\d+-\d+
```

this regex will match all the strings until it reaches the `pid-12-12`.